# CSS Sprite background repeat

Tags: css, css-sprites

Background image repeat-x Or y not work for me.

HTML :

```
<div id="box">
 <div class="t"></div>
 <div class="m"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#box{width:220px; height: 230px; margin:0 auto; }
#box .t {width:220px;height:40px; margin:0 auto;background-image:url(../images/main.png) ;background-position:0 0; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#box .m {width:220px;height:180px; margin:0 auto;background:url(../images/main.png) repeat-x  0 -40px;} */repeat-y */
#box .b {width:220px;height:10px; margin:0 auto;}
```

This Printed only background of m class without repeat-x or y . How To Fix This ?
this type of writing css for sprite is optimized?

Thanks.

Online Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cAbYF/

Comment: could you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) your code please?

Comment: Also we need to know how large your images are compared to the divs.

Comment: pleasedontbelong and @stommepoes : http://jsfiddle.net/cAbYF/

Comment: It's working - http://jsfiddle.net/cAbYF/1/  Your `<div>` is just to narrow to show the repeated background

Comment: @Zoltan Toth : In Fact, My Mean Is repeat-y . in repeat-y not repeat blue border of 180px height div.

Comment: I see.. In that case it's not possible. The browser can't repeat just a part of the BG image - it repeats the whole one. You can't get blue side borders unless you make them as high as you need and position that

Comment: Also if you repeat-y then you won't be able to set where it starts with something  like background-position: 0 -46px, that -46px is on the y axis and the browser will start from the top. Similar, with repeat-x, can't do something like 50% 0 either.

Answer (score 1):

You have repeated images in fixed width ex:(repeat-x means width:1px; one by one image)(repeat-y means height:1px; floating image) to give perfect image it also repeat correctly.)